# I need to find the convergence interval for a trigonometric series.

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry, convergence-divergence

$$\Sigma^{\infty}_{n=1} \frac{\cos (\pi n) \sin \left(\pi x \right)}{(n+1)n \cot^n x} \le \frac{1}{n(n+1) \cot^n x} = \left[ y = \cot^n x \right] \\ \text{Due to necessary condition for convergence: } \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n(n+1)y} = 0 \Rightarrow y \neq 0 $$ So, originally function $\cot x$ is defined everywhere. So, $x \in R $ except for $n\pi, \ \ n\in Z$, but in this case the domain for the function cannot take an arguments of $\frac{\pi n}{2}$, Is this correct? So the convergence domain is equal to $x \in  ] \pi k + \frac{\pi}{2}; \frac{3\pi k}{2} + \frac{\pi}{2}[, \ \ k \in Z$. Is this correct? Furthermore, how can I find a sum for these series?